# NetFileEnum and C++

Tags: c++

I don't know C++ at all.  But I am trying to slightly alter a C++ project that someone created that shows you who has what files open on the network.

The project works perfectly after a bit of work getting it to work with the latest VS.

The list box is populated with Paths and usernames.  The paths consist of paths and paths with filename at the end.  For example

(just edited this line, missed the \ at the end)

C:\Data\Work\

C:\Data\Work\Accounting.xls

The alteration I'm having trouble doing is I wanted to add an If statement while its loading the listbox and not load any pathnames that end in "\".  So the listbox ends up only showing actual paths to files.  In the above example it would not add the first path to the listbox and would add the second.

Here is the code snippet that works except for the If statement.  I'm having trouble wrapping my head around Strings, literals, LPCTSTR, wchar, etc. :)

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;

dwStatus = NetFileEnum((LPWSTR) ((LPCTSTR) strServer), NULL, NULL, 3, (LPBYTE *) &pBuffer, MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH, &dwReadEntries, &dwTotalEntries, NULL);
if (NERR_Success == dwStatus)
{
    for (dwIndex = 0, pCurrent = pBuffer; dwIndex < dwReadEntries; dwIndex++, pCurrent++)
    {
        tstring mystring = pCurrent->fi3_pathname;

        //MessageBox(mystring.c_str()), NULL,MB_OK);

        if (mystring[mystring.length() -1] != L'\'')
        {
            nItem = m_lcFiles.InsertItem(dwIndex, pCurrent->fi3_pathname);
            m_lcFiles.SetItemText(nItem, 1, pCurrent->fi3_username);
        }
    }

    NetApiBufferFree(pBuffer);
}
```

Comment: This is a wrong approach. Your first path does not contain trailing \ symbol, yet this is a directory path. Use `GetFileAttributes` instead.

Comment: Sorry, thats a typo, I'll edit it right now.  I don't think GetFileAttributes is available, this is run on a workstation and through the NetFileEnumm API it gets all the open files on a server.  Its actually works great, just wanted to filer out all the path's only and show the files only since you can get a lot of entries to scroll thorugh looking for your one file that is open.

Comment: it does not work because you're comparing a character with a string.

Comment: OK, I'm not familiar with C++ strings, pointers, etc.  Used to VB.  It took me hours just to get to this point with out any compiler errors.  Any thoughts on how to compare the last character in pcurrent->fi3_pathname to see if its a "\" character?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Doh, I figured it our.  The \ character is a special character of course, the escape sequence.  So I had to compare to "\".

Works now, thanks!

Comment: Dang, typo, should say "\\"